# How do I start MoviePlayer without controls?

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayer

I would like to start the MoviePlyer without controls, but if the user touch the screen, the controls are displayed and allow user to go full screen or AirPlay.

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
self.player.allowsAirPlay = YES;
self.player.view.frame = self.imageView.frame;
self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
[self.player play];

self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
```

It seems that the only way to remove controls initially is to set to MPMovieControlStyleNone, but no controls will be shown later. If I set to MPMovieControlStyleDefault later, controls will always be shown.

What should I do? Is there a property to set controls to off initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate on [Open video in iPhone without controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043670/open-video-in-iphone-without-controls) and
[Playing a video on startup of app without controlshere](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/92812-playing-a-video-on-startup-of-app-without-controls.html)

Comment: The first link works, although you will need to change the deprecated method name to the new one.